# What are they talking about when they talk about "uniqued types" and "types in LLVM are uniqued"?

Tags: types, llvm

This must be stupid, but I do not understand the meaning when they say "types in LLVM are uniqued" (See [this tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html), section 3.4).  Would you kindly  explain me what is this so-called "uniqued type" ( "LLVM types are uniqued" should be easy to follow once "uniqued type" is clear.)

Comment: can you cite where they say "Types in LLVM are uniqued"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that two types that have the same content are actually the same type. This is why you don't *create* a new type when you want a "double(double, double)" type, you instead *get the existing* "double(double, double)" type - if there's none it will be created for you, if there's already one it will be returned.

This is the common case in LLVM, with the notable exception that [identified *structural* types in LLVM *are* uniqued by name and not structure](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#structure-types). "Identified structural type" means a struct type which has an associated name.

In general, this is related to the concept of [nominal types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) vs. [structural types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).

Comment: I see. Just the singleton pattern. Thanks.

Comment: @zell it's not entirely singleton (it's per context) and it's not universal for all types (see my note about identified structural type), but I agree that it's definitely in the spirit of using singletons, I should have probably used that word :-) I'm glad you understood anyway.